# Efficiently store a large amount of variable inside a class

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm creating an application (C#) that uses a database (with a single table, it's only for query) with customers data in it.
The problem is that I need to create a class to represent the database customers item so I can use it inside my code and it have ~50 fields which are all important and not related.
I don't think creating a class with 50 declared variable is a viable solution, so I thought about using a `Dictionary` but I don't think it will be easy for anyone else to read the code afterward.
It there a way to store large amount of values inside 1 class without declaring a lot of variable, but to be still able to differentiate them ?

Comment: Do you have any evidence that you've actually got a memory problem in the first place? Why don't you think that a class with 50 variables is a viable solution? (It's not *pleasant*, but that's what you get for trying to mirror a database table which has lots of unrelated columns.)

Comment: Entity Framework is made for this

Comment: I never said that it will cause memory problem, but I already worked with class that had a lot of variable and it make the coding way more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. Use Entity Framework: He will generate your class with properties automatically.
2. Use a DataTable.
3. Use a Dictionary.

For option 2 and 3, to improve readabiliy, create a class with constant column names, like:

```
class CostumerColumnNames
{
     public const string FirstName = "FirstName";
     public const string LastName = "LastName";
     // etc.
}
```

Now you can use it very simply like:

```
 string value = myDict[CostumerColumnNames.FirstName];
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a Dictionary is a good call for this type of problem.

If you worry about future developer just write proper class documentation and this will solve the problem.